# Android - why the "content://sms/sent" only return one result?

Tags: android, sms, messaging

When trying to retrieve the sent sms I see that the uri sms/sent only return 1 sms (although the device has more) and it seems that it's the first sent sms. How can I get all the sms in the sent box? I can't use the Telephony class because it's API level 19.

Comment: I would guess that either your query is wrong, or you're not iterating over the Cursor correctly. We can't know without seeing your code.

Comment: @MikeM. its the simple do{ }while (cursor.moveToNext()); loop. Sorry I don't have the code right now.

Comment: How are you determining that there's only one message returned? Are you checking `Cursor#getCount()`, or are you going by the count of some collection you're building in the loop?

Comment: also I don't think my code is wrong since I can fetch all the inbox sms using that approach, just replace the sms/inbox with sms/sent

Comment: @MikeM. I check directly in the device, in my app it shows only the first sent sms and in the stock messaging there are more. I get count from adapter

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Without seeing your code, it's just guesswork. And since your getting the count from (what I'm presuming is) a ListView Adapter, that's just another place where several different problems could arise. I suggest that, when you get back to your code, the first thing you check is the Cursor's count immediately after the query.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you I figured out where I messed up.